# Submenu not showing up under Tools

Tags: php, wordpress

So I'm wanting to define a new submenu within one of my .php files under mu-plugins folder and I'm receiving the below error:

> user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function
>   'register_my_custom_submenu_page' not found or invalid function name
>   in
>   /Users/*****/Sites/******.com/www/htdocs/wordpress/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 286

**Breadcrumbs**:

> wp-content -> mu-plugins -> insta.php

**Here is the code**:

```
function register_my_custom_submenu_page() {
    add_submenu_page(
        'tools.php',
        'Submenu Page',
        'My Custom Submenu Page',
        'manage_options',
        'my-custom-submenu-page' );
}

add_action('admin_menu', 'register_my_custom_submenu_page');
```

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong? **I can't change/add anything inside the wordpress core files due to version control.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow the below code to add submenu under tools.

```
add_action('init', 'books_register_ref_page');

/**
 * Adds a submenu page under a custom post type parent.
 */

function books_register_ref_page() {
    add_submenu_page(
        'tools.php',
        __( 'Submenu Page', 'textdomain' ),
        __( 'Submenu Page', 'textdomain' ),
        'manage_options',
        'my-custom-submenu-page',
        'my_custom_submenu_page_callback'
    );
}

/**
 * Display callback for the submenu page.
 */
function my_custom_submenu_page_callback() { 
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h1><?php _e( 'Submenu Page', 'textdomain' ); ?></h1>
        <p><?php _e( 'Helpful stuff here', 'textdomain' ); ?></p>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

For more help please follow WordPress function reference.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_submenu_page/